# Spark streaming - waiting for data for window aggregations?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have data in the format { host | metric | value | time-stamp }.  We have hosts all around the world reporting metrics.

I'm a little confused about using window operations (say, 1 hour) to process data like this.

- Can I tell my window when to start, or does it just start when the application starts?  I want to ensure I'm aggregating all data from hour 11 of the day, for example.  If my window starts at 10:50, I'll just get 10:50-11:50 and miss 10 minutes.
- Even if the window is perfect, data may arrive late.

How do people handle this kind of issue? Do they make windows far bigger than needed and just grab the data they care about on every batch cycle (kind of sliding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I worked on a large-scale IoT platform and solved that problem by considering that the windows were only partial calculations. I modeled the backend (Cassandra) to receive more than 1 record for each window. The actual value of any given window would be the addition of all -potentially partial- records found for that window.

So, a perfect window would be 1 record, a split window would be 2 records, late-arrivals are naturally supported but only accepted up to a certain 'age' threshold.  Reconciliation was done at read time. As this platform was orders of magnitude heavier in terms of writes vs reads, it made for a good compromise.

Comment: That's an interesting option; thank you for sharing :).  It sounds a little bit like how OpenTSDB solves the problem now that you mention it.  I'll consider how that might work in my case.

Comment: I'll accept this as a viable answer and add my own I got from some other forms as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After speaking with people in depth on MapR forums, the consensus seems to be that hourly and daily aggregations should not be done in a stream, but rather in a separate batch job once the data is ready.

When doing streaming you should stick to small batches with windows that are relatively small multiples of the streaming interval.  Sliding windows can be useful for, say, trends over the last 50 batches.  Using them for tasks as large as an hour or a day doesn't seem sensible though.

Also, I don't believe you can tell your batches when to start/stop, etc.